# How do I switch between 2 outputs with this condition?

Tags: transistors

[image: Truth Table]

I'm looking for ways to power 2 separate LEDs with the following conditions.
I'll be using 2 switches and BC547 transistors to do it. I'm figuring out how to lay this out on multisim so I could test it out.

---

[image: LOGIC GATE]
I've come up with this using Logic Gate symbols and it works. XOR and XNOR. I'm trying to find samples of its transistor circuit counterparts but have trouble doing so. Does anyone know a reference or could help out? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What logic gate should you consider? What logic gates are you aware of?

Comment: Looks like exclusive or and invertor.

Comment: Yep, LED 1 is XOR, LED 2 is !XOR. Find most basic implementations of those circuits and try something yourself first. And post here.

Comment: @andyaka So far I've tried The XOR and XNOR cause it lines up. Although I'm not quite sure because I'm still learning it.

Comment: @user263983 I'll consider this, thank you very much!

Comment: @Ilya Thank you for the advice. I will try using this in my draft. I'll post it here when it is done :D

Comment: @JustineOgapong - Hi, You posted an "answer", but it was still asking for advice. Therefore it should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box and it has been moved into the question as an edit i.e. as an update instead. *Unless* you are writing the *final conclusion* to your own question, without using any other answers (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new information or updates etc. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.